# How to remove an element from json string before deserialize it?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Let's say the return type is

```
    public ActionResult Balance()
    {
        var myDtos = new List<BalanceModelDto>();
        return Ok(new {data = myDtos});
    }
```

and in my xunit, I assert the return type.

```
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {                          
            var response = await client.GetAsync($"/Balance");
            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BalanceModelDto>(responseString);

            Assert.IsType<BalanceModelDto>(result);

            Assert.Equal(1, result.Balance);
        }
```

The problem is `responseString` is `"{\"data\":[{"balance\":1}]}"`. But what I want is just `"[{"balance\":1}]"`

Comment: `"{[{"balance\":1}]}"` is not valid json

Comment: Why would you assert something that is not true? Maybe just assert correct type actually returned by your api?

Comment: _why_ are you putting the `myDtos` into a `data` object? Do you need `data` anywhere else? Else see the answer below: you can just use `myDtos` directly.

Comment: I can't remove 'data'. It is there for long time. Legacy code

Comment: @JL0PD, sorry, updated to `"[{"balance\":1}]"`

Comment: I can't remove/modify this anonymous type `new {data}`. So the problem is when I `DeserializeObject`, I do not know what type to put.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deserialize into `JObject`:

```
var responseRaw = (JObject) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseString);
```

Then convert "data" property of that json object into `BalanceModelDto[]`:

```
var result = responseRaw["data"].ToObject<BalanceModelDto[]>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Either: you should be looking at `result.data` instead of just `result`.
or: `return Ok(myDtos);` from the ActionMethod.

Comment: He's not showing `BalanceModelDto`... that probably only has a `balance` property, so it won't deserialize. But you have a valid point.

Comment: You mean `Assert.IsType<BalanceModelDto>(result.data);`? I tried but syntax error.